# Laravel : how to execute controller function on button in view?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to call controller function in view page.

Here is function code :

```
 public function annulerSeanceConduite(Request $request,SeanceConduite $seanceConduite)
{
    //

    $seanceConduite->statut = "Annulée";

    $seanceConduite->save();
    $request->session()->flash('message', 'Seance Conduite est annulée!');
    return redirect('seanceConduites');

}
```

And the route :

```
Route::get('annulerSeanceConduite', 'SeanceConduiteController@annulerSeanceConduite');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign name to your Route when you define it and use that name to generate the correct URL in your view file

```
Route::get('/annulerSeance/{id}', 'SeanceConduiteController@annulerSeanceConduite')
         ->name('annulerSeance');
```

and in your view file you use it like this

```
<a href="{{ route('annulerSeance', ['id' => $seanceConduite->id ]) }}">Annuler</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a button, you could use a normal "a", or bind the link the the specified route to an onclick event on the button.

Comment: I tried " <a href="{{ URL::to('annulerSeanceConduite/' . $seanceConduite->id ) }}"> annuler</a> " but it redirect me to 404 not found ..